# “.htaccess” and “.htpasswd" access policies

Tags: html, .htaccess

This problem might be easy, but I am really stuck. I am new to using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files. I have an `index.html` file that points to 3 different courses (all in the same directory).

Comment: You need to define a separate password file for each html file !

Comment: Would you please be more specific? You mean 3 .htpasswd? each one for each user?

Comment: yes, 3 `.htpasswd`s! one for each file !

Comment: I cannot do that, because as I mentioned, all the 3 files are in the same directory, which means I cannot create 3 .htpasswd in the same directory and I am not allowed to move the 3 files to other directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<Files A1.htm> 
require user Nancy Bob
</Files>
<Files A2.htm>
require user Nancy Bob
</Files>
<Files A3.htm>
require user Nancy Randy
</Files>
```